# How to reach postgres maximum connection with sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

This is related to `sqlalchemy` and `pg8000`.

I have read everywhere that I should close the `ResultProxy` object so that connection could be returned to the pool.

The local test database allows a maximum of `100` connections:

```
$ psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres
Password for user postgres: 
psql (9.5.5, server 9.6.0)
WARNING: psql major version 9.5, server major version 9.6.
         Some psql features might not work.
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# show max_connections;
 max_connections 
-----------------
 100
(1 row)
```

The following test script creates an engine in every loop and does not read nor close the `ResultProxy` object. It really is as bad as it can get.

The weird thing is, it also does not generate a `too many connections` kind of error. This is really confusing to me. Does sqlalchemy performs some magic? Or maybe `postgres` is actually magic?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
from __future__ import print_function
import sqlalchemy

def handle():
    url = 'postgresql+pg8000://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'
    url = url.format("postgres", "pass", "127.0.0.1", "5432", "usercity")
    conn = sqlalchemy.create_engine(url, client_encoding='utf8')
    meta = sqlalchemy.MetaData(bind=conn, reflect=True)
    table = meta.tables['events']
    clause = table.select()
    result = conn.execute(clause)


if __name__=='__main__':
    for i in range(2000):
        print(i)
        handle()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No magic, just garbage collection.  Since `handle()` doesn't return anything (or modify global data), there is no way for a reference to the connection or cursor it creates to live beyond the scope of `handle()`.  When they go out of scope, their reference counts drop to 0, and they get deleted (there is no hard guarantee about when this happens, but in practice, in CPython this happens immediately).

Comment: Thank you, that makes total sense. Tested and verified.